# How to get indexes of values that satisfy a filter?

Tags: java, apache-spark

In Spark, I can apply a filter to a RDD to create a new one one s.t each element of that RDD satisfy the filter as follows:

```
JavaRDD<Integer> vals = sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(10, 15, 0, 6, 2));
    JavaRDD<Integer> valsGreaterThan5 = vals.filter(new Function<Integer, Boolean>() {
        public Boolean call(Integer x) {
            if (x > 5)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    });
```

So, this code will return me a new RDD that contains 10, 15 and 6. However, what should I had to do if I wanted to get their indexes? So instead of **10, 15 and 6**, I want their indexes which are **0, 1, 3.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create RDD from pairs `<index, value>`, so than you will be able to filter by values, and map from pairs to indexes then.

UPD:
Something like this (I don't have Spark near me so can't ensure if it compiles):

```
     JavaPairRDD<Integer> vals = sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(
      new Tuple2(0, 10),
      new Tuple2(1, 15), 
      new Tuple2(2, 0), 
      new Tuple2(3, 6), 
      new Tuple2(4, 2)));
    JavaRDD<Integer> valsGreaterThan5 = vals.filter(new Function<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>, Boolean>() {
        public Boolean call(Tuple2<Integer, Integer> x) {
            return (x._2 > 5);
        }
    }).map(new Function<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>, Integer>() {
        public Boolean call(Tuple2<Integer, Integer> x) {
           return x._1;
        }
    });
```

I hope you hava got the idea. Also you can make the code looks much better with lambdas.

UPD2:
 with lambdas logic block could looks like:

```
JavaRDD<Integer> valsGreaterThan5 = vals
    .filter((x) -> x._2 > 5)
    .map((x) -> x._1);
```

Comment: Is it possible to illustrate a bit with code ? I'm beginner and this doesn't make much sense to me at the moment :)

Comment: Thanks I got the idea. However, the syntax is wrong and I can't figure it out. I try something like:JavaPairRDD vals = sc
    .parallelize(Arrays.asList(10, 15, 0))
    .zipWithIndex();
  JavaPairRDD valsGreaterThan5 = vals
       .filter((k, v) -> v > 5)
       .map((k, v) -> k);